# Django ORM: Perform conditional `order_by`

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Say one has this simple model:

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    n = models.IntegerField()
```

In SQL you can perform an order by with a condition
e.g.

`select * from foo orber by n=7, n=17, n=3, n`

This will sort the rows by first if `n` is 7, then if `n` is 14, then if `n` is 3, and then finally by n ascending.

How does one do the same with the Django ORM? It is not covered in their [`order_by` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by).

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case

Comment: This will actually order in the opposite order, since `False` is less than `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with a generic solution that looks like:

```
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, When, Value

items = [7, 17, 3]
Foo.objects.alias(
    n_order=Case(
        *[When(n=item, then=Value(i)) for i, item in enumerate(items)],
        default=Value(len(items)),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
).order_by('n_order', 'n')
```

This thus constructs a [*conditional expression* chain <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions) that is used first, and if `n` is not one of these, it will fall back on ordering with `n` itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.annotate()` to assign records a `custom_order` value and use then `.order_by()` to order the queryset based on this value.

For example:

```
Foo.objects \
.annotate(custom_order=Case( 
    When(n=7, then=Value(0)), 
    When(n=17, then=Value(1)), 
    When(n=3, then=Value(2)),
    default=Value(3),
    output_field=IntegerField()
 ) \
.order_by('custom_order', 'n')
```

Comment: Thanks, that is nice and easy to understandhowever it just needs `order_by('n_order', 'n')` as per @Willem's answer below.

Comment: Yeah you're absolutely right! Updated the answer accordingly

Comment: @HarunYilmaz: another small detail is that `.order_by(..)` orders from small-to-large by default, hence the `Value(3)`, etc. will put `n=7` last and `n=17` second to last. You should use `-custom_order`, or reverse the values.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I was just adding a comment on your answer to see if it's in a reverse order haha :D You're right, too. Thanks